# Acessing and add records from other controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a model

```
class Rcomment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :comment, :rating

  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I'm trying to add comment via the show view of recipe. I populated rcomment table with dummy data and it's showing fine via:

```
@recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
@comments = @recipe.rcomments
```

So I tried 
    @newcomments = @recipe.rcomments.build(params[:recipe])

But it doesn't work at all with an error:
    undefined method `rcomments_path' for #<#:0x25ccd10>

How do I get it to display a usable form_for?

```
%= form_for(@newcomments) do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :Comments %>
      <%= f.text_field :comment%>

      <%= f.label :ratings %>
      <%= f.text_field :rating %>

      <%= f.submit "Submit Comment", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've created a form for Rcomment creation, but you don't have an rcomments entry in your routes.rb. However, I think what best fits your problem is creating rcomments through a recipe. You can do this with `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and `fields_for`.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

So, something like this--

In your Recipe model, add:

```
attr_accessible :rcomments_attributes
accepts_nested_attributes_for :rcomments
```

And in your recipes#show view:

```
<%= form_for(@recipe) do |f| %>
  <% f.fields_for :rcomments do |cf| %>
    <%= cf.label "Comments" %>
    <%= cf.text_field :comment%>

    <%= cf.label "Ratings" %>
    <%= cf.text_field :rating %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit "Submit Comment", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The above stops the error but the form_for does not show, only the button, and it will gives error The action 'update' could not be found for RecipesController